# How do I explore git colors?

Tags: git, git-config

The git book in 8.1 Customizing Git - Git Configuration has a [section](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_colors_in_git) which describes how to change colors of the output. In my current case, I'd like to change the color of diff "removed" from dim red to red. But actually I want to do more adjustments, which leads to the following problem:

> to set certain color setting I need to know its name

The section mentions `color.branch`, `color.diff`, `color.interactive`, `color.status`; `color.diff.meta`. But what are the rest "properties of `color.diff`"? Which one corresponds to the "removed" bits? I've tried `git config --get color.diff` and got `auto`; `git config --get color.diff.meta` and got an empty response.

How do I get the list of all color options? (and their values)

Comment: The values appear to be listed in the manual (`man git-config`), from about line 1070 to 1200 (for git 2.26 anyway). Try searching for `color\.\w`.

Comment: [`git config --get-color name`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---get-colorboolnamestdout-is-tty), [colors](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-color), [`color.*`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coloradvice).

Comment: a couple of commands that I've used already to improve the brightness problem: `git config --global color.status.changed "red normal bold"`, `git config --global color.status.untracked "red normal bold"` (instead of `man git-config` used `git config --help`)